# Pass post title as URL parameter

Tags: urls, parameter

On my site/blog, I have one landing page, through which I collect all ‘Consultation Requests’ – let’s call it:

```
http://example.com/conso-request/
```

On every page/post of the site is a navigation link, with the text ‘Request Information’.

For each page/post that CTA appears, I want it to have a unique URL which passes the post/page title to my landing page, e.g. `http://example.com/conso-request/?xxx=my-great-post`

I've got the element id to work with btw.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the new link by hook will be the best way.

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {

    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;

    $landinglink = '<li class="home"><a href="' .get_page_link('YOUR_LANDING_PAGE_ID_HERE').'?from='.$post_slug.'">' . __('BLAA') . '</a></li>';
    $items = $items . $landinglink;
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Change 'YOUR_LANDING_PAGE_ID_HERE' with landing page ID.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot - sorry I'm new to this. How do I use this?

Comment: just place this code in functions.php of your theme. And you are good to go. Just keep in mind to change 'YOUR_LANDING_PAGE_ID_HERE' with landing page ID.